# Get results of request with sort and limit using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb-query, pymongo

Let's take this simple collection `col` with 2 documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca4bf475e7a8e4881ef9dd2"),
    "timestamp" : 1551736800,
    "score" : 10
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca4bf475e7a8e4881ef9dd3"),
    "timestamp" : 1551737400,
    "score" : 12
}
```

To access the last timestamp (the one of the second document), I first did this request

```
a = db['col'].find({}).sort("_id", -1)
```

and then `a[0]['timestamp']`

But as there will be a lot of documents in this collection, i think that it would be more efficient to request only the last one with the limit function, like

```
a = db['col'].find({}).sort("_id", -1).limit(1)
```

and then

```
for doc in a:
    lastTimestamp = doc['timestamp']
```

as there will be only one, i can declare the variable inside the loop.

So three questions :

- Do i have to worry about memory / speed issues if i continue to use the first request and get the first element in the dic ?
- Is there a smarter way to access the first element of the cursor instead of using a loop, when using the limit request ?
- Is there another way to get that timestamp that i don't know ?

Thanks !
Python 3.6 / Pymongo 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any field with an unique index in the selection criteria, you should use `find_one` method which will return the only document that matches your query.

That being said, the `find` method returns a Cursor object and does not load the data into memory.

You might get a better performance if you where using a filter option. Your query as it is now will do a collection scan.

if you are not using a filter, and want to retrieve the last document, then the clean way is with the Python built-in `next` function. You could also use the [`next`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.next) method.

```
cur = db["col"].find().sort({"_id": -1}).limit(1):
with cur:
    doc = next(cur, None) # None when we have empty collection.
```

Comment: thanks, i didn't know about the filter, i'll check that !

Comment: what's the point of `with` here ? Can't we directly do `doc = next(cur, None)`

Comment: `with` is used here to close the cursor @TmSmth

Answer (score 0):

find().sort() is so fast and don't worry about the speed and it's the best access the first element of the cursor.